# Can a function $f$ be continuous at a point $a$ even if $a$ is not a limit point of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definition

Suppose we adopt the following definitions of a limit and continuity:

**Definition of a Limit**

Suppose a function $\DeclareMathOperator{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}f:D\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point at $a$, i.e. for every $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in D$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$. We say that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$ iff

> For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $x\in D$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

**Definition of continuity**

Suppose a function $f:D\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is defined at the point $a$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff

> For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $x\in D$ and $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

The problem I have is this: the definition of continuity is often abbreviated to

> $f:D\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ iff $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

However, according to the definitions I have presented, it seems that there might be cases where $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ does not exist, and yet it is still the case that $f$ is continuous at $a$. For example, consider the function $\phi=\{(0,0)\}$. This function is trivially continuous at $0$, but $\lim_{x \to 0}\phi(x)$ does not exist because $0$ is not a limit point of $\phi$. So are the two definitions of continuity only equivalent if $a$ is a limit point of $f$?

I have one further question. The definition of a limit requires that $a$ be a limit point of $f$. Is this restriction necessary because otherwise we could argue things like $\lim_{x \to 0}\phi(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}\phi(x)=2$ are both vacuously true?

Comment: The abbreviation of the definition of continuity you refer to is one that only works when $D$ is a space with the properties you mention. In fact, without these properties on $D$ at point $a$, any function is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Your use of the term [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) here is not quite right: (roughly speaking) sets have limit points, not functions. The definition of the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to a$ that you give is standard and has the rather odd consequence that $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$ for any $L$ if $a$ is an isolated point of the domain of $f$. $(0, 0)$ is not a limit point of the **graph** of the function $\phi = \{(0, 0)\}$ and $0$ is not a limit point of the **domain** of $\phi$, but $\phi(x) \to L$ for any $L$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @RobArthan: So, are you saying that $a$ is a limit point of $D$, but is not a limit point of $f$?

Comment: I am saying that it is not standard to talk about "limit points" of functions. What you are calling the limit point of a function is a limit point of the domain of the function. The definitions you quote for $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and for continuity of $f$ at $a$ do not require $a$ to be a limit point of the domain (and if it isn't, any value will do as the limit as $x \to a$ and $f$ will always be continuous at $a$).

Comment: @RobArthan: Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks. Having looked at the Wikipedia article you have linked, I can see that a point $a$ is a limit point of a set $D$ if every neighbourhood of $a$ contains at least one point $x$ such that $x\in D$. But the set $D$ has to be a *topological space* for the definition to apply, and a set of ordered pairs (i.e. a function) is not a topological space. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @RobArthan: Regarding the definition of a limit, my idea was that we require that $a$ be a limit point of the domain of $f$ because otherwise a function $f$ might have more than one limit as $x \to a$. If we take this approach, then we cannot regard $\lim_{x \to a}$ as a (partial) function.

Comment: Yes. Both your last two comments are right. (1) You can think of the **graph** of a function as a topological space, but it is the domain that's relevant here. And for the definitions of $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and continuity of $f$ at $a$ it doesn't matter whether $a$ is a limit point of the domain. (N.b., in the definition of $a$ as a limit point of $D$, every neighbourhood of $a$ must contain an $x \neq a$ with $x \in D$ - isolated points don't count as limit points.) (2) $\lim_{x\to a}$ is not a partial function for the reasons discussed.

Comment: Another example where the (incorrectly) abbreviated version doesn't work: $f(x)=\sqrt{x^4-x^2}$ at $x=0$. We really want this function to be continuous, since otherwise we would have to give up the theorem that a composition of continuous functions is continuous, but then we must accept that it's continuous at the origin, which is an isolated point in the domain $D_f$ (so that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is meaningless).

Comment: @HansLundmark: That's a very good point, and I think it is a good example of why the abbreviated definition doesn't work unless there is a neighbourhood of $a$ for which $f$ is defined. I have one question: it is easy to show that the function $f(x)=x$, where $x$ is an integer, is continuous. However, this fact runs contrary to our *intuitive* notion of continuity, where we able to draw the graph of $f$ without lifting a pencil off the page. So what is the motivation behind defining continuity in this way? Why is this definition useful?

Comment: @HansLundmark: My point is that often in mathematics, when we try to formalise an intuitive concept and it doesn't work out, we change the definition of that concept to better match our intuition. However, in the case of continuity, it seems that people actually found it *useful* for a function to be continuous at isolated points in its domain (otherwise we would changed the definition). So why is defining continuity in this way helpful?

Comment: That thing with not lifting the pencil is another example of not-quite-right simplification (albeit with a grain a truth). It only works over an interval in the domain. If the domain has “holes”, then we *must* lift the pencil in order to draw the graph, since we're not allowed to draw values where there aren't any. And if the curve length of the graph is infinite (like for Weierstrass's nowhere differentiable function), then it doesn't really work over an interval either, since we would need an infinite amount of pencil.

Comment: The reason that the currently accepted definition of continuity has been found useful (and therefore accepted) is that you get the theorems that you want: the extreme value theorem, the intermediate value theorem, composition and arithmetical operations preserve continuity, etc. If your intuition doesn't match the definition, it's the intuition that needs to be tuned, not the other way around.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thanks for the information. However, I thought theorems such as the extreme value theorem only apply to functions which are continuous on $[a,b]$, and so it would not apply to a function with an isolated point in the interval $[a,b]$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The extreme value theorem (or at least one version of it) says that if $f \colon K \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous, where $K$ is a compact set (in any topological space), then there are points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $K$ such that $f(x_1) \le f(x) \le f(x_2)$ for all $x \in K$. The case $K = [a,b] \subset \mathbf{R}$ is one particular instance of it. I don't understand what you mean by “a function with an isolated point in the interval $[a,b]$”.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is more specific to intervals, however. The theorem that $f \circ g$ is continuous if $f$ and $g$ are is completely general.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Sorry, what I mean by "a function with an isolated point in the interval $[a,b]$" is a function that has a point $c\in[a,b]$ where $c$ is an isolated point in the domain of $f$. Does this not make sense?

Comment: If you want to apply the extreme value theorem on a set $K$, the function $f$ must be defined on $K$ to begin with, so clearly in that case you cannot apply the theorem on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @HansLundmark: Okay. My point was that as far as the extreme value is concerned, it does not matter if functions with isolated points are continuous there or not (either way, the extreme value theorem wouldn't apply to such functions). But I take your point about $f \circ g$ being continuous if $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Thanks for all of your help!